# Show / update components before process finished

Tags: java, swing, executorservice

I currently have a java program with swing gui that lets the user choose various files (xsl-fo and xml) and generates PDFs using Render X. I have trying for a while to get a pop up JFrame to appear when a button is pressed, which would then show a progress bar, or label to keep the user informed of the progress. However when instantiating a new frame it will appear black, or without components, which then show after the processes have completed.

```
private void RunButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    //for reach file to process)
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new ProcessThreader(conf, i);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    JFrame PercentageFrame = new JFrame();
    PercentageFrame.setVisible(true);
    PercentageFrame.setSize(200, 200);
    PercentageFrame.repaint();

    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            NarrowOptionPane.errorMessage("Interrupted: ", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Complete");
}
```

The run button is located in a JPanel, which is located in a JFrame and the Main Frame is instantiated in the main method, and wrapped in the invoke later method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new MainFrame("PDF Producer");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(710, 530);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm fairly new to threading / executors and java swing, so go easy! Thanks

Comment: remove `while` loop it must help you, also update your PercentageFrame from `ProcessThreader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop block `EDT`, delete that and your code will be work.

See next example with `ExecutorService` and `JProgressBar` :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    private static JProgressBar progress;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        progress = new JProgressBar();
        progress.setStringPainted(true);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for( int i =0; i<10;i++){
            final int j = i;
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progress.setString(j+"");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            newCachedThreadPool.submit(r);
        }
        f.getContentPane().add(progress,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Here `JFrame` show number of `Runnable` which executed in `ExecutorService`. Also if you need to get result from your Runnables, try to use `Callable` instead of `Runnable`. With that when you `submit` `Callable` you get `Future` instance from which you can get result.

Read about [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: For reference, a `SwingWorker` implements `Runnable`, `Future<T>`, & `RunnableFuture<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

Code executed from within a listener is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread. So the Thread.sleep() is causing the EDT to sleep which means the GUI can't respond to events or repaint itself.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency In Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. One solution as described in the tutorial is to use a `SwingWorker` for the long running task and to publish results as they become available.